# How to code a special endless scroll website?

Tags: javascript, html

I checked a lot of endless scroll scripts and was not happy with any of them.

What I want to have is in general this:

```
window.onscroll = function(ev) {
    if ((window.innerHeight + window.scrollY) >= document.body.offsetHeight) {
        //same HTML document starts again without reloading
    }
};
```

How is it possible to code this?

Comment: You can code this using the code you provided, but you need to take into consideration that you will also need to throttle the scroll event and also take into consideration resizing (the user rotates the screen and it's now on the landscape mode so the screen height has changed)

Answer (score 1):

You can use an `IntersectionObserver` to get notified when your view is reaching the end to continue loading more content i.e. infinite scroll, what you want to achieve.

```
let options = {
  root: document.querySelector('#scrollArea'),
  rootMargin: '0px',
  threshold: 1.0
}

let callback = (entries, observer) => { 
  entries.forEach(entry => {
    // Each entry describes an intersection change for one observed
    // target element:
    //   entry.boundingClientRect
    //   entry.intersectionRatio
    //   entry.intersectionRect
    //   entry.isIntersecting
    //   entry.rootBounds
    //   entry.target
    //   entry.time
  });
};

let observer = new IntersectionObserver(callback, options);

let target = document.querySelector('#listItem');
observer.observe(target);
```

To get the complete guide, check out the very detailed [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API)

Comment: Just an FYI: this API is not supported on IE and safari < 12. If you need support for those browsers here is the official polyfill  [link](https://github.com/w3c/IntersectionObserver/tree/master/polyfill)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. Could you write it as full code please?

Answer (score 0):

**ONLY If you are using React JS or planning to use it and your concern is performance**

You can take a look on this [react-window](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-window) library so it will efficiently only render the ones on the window view:

https://codesandbox.io/s/x70ly749rq - if you inspect element the list on this sandbox, you will see that the previous set of list are remove from the dom making your site not slow despite of so much data that you previously loaded.

It goes hand in hand with [react-window-infinite-loader](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-window-infinite-loader/)